# How to use fixture in combination of Django TestCase when unit testing with modified Django settings?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, settings, fixtures

In a Django project, I want to override a setting for a unit test. From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.modify_settings), it seems the recommended way seems to use a `TestCase` and using methods like `modify_settings` or `override_settings`. This is the example given:

```py
from django.test import TestCase


class MiddlewareTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_cache_middleware(self):
        with self.modify_settings(
            MIDDLEWARE={
                "append": "django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
                "prepend": "django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
                "remove": [
                    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
                    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
                    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
                ],
            }
        ):
            response = self.client.get("/")
            # ...
```

When using Django `TestCase` (and override_setting) my test fixtures that are annotated using `@pytest.fixture` are no longer recognized.

This is a minimal example that reproduce my issue.

```py
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

@pytest.fixture
def my_client():
    return APIClient()


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("my_client")
class TestLogin(TestCase):
    def test_jwt_expiration(self):
        simple_jwt_settings = settings.SIMPLE_JWT
        # Force a very short lifetime for the access token
        simple_jwt_settings['ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME'] = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=1)
        with override_settings(SIMPLE_JWT=simple_jwt_settings):
            response = self.my_client.get("/login")
            assert response.status_code == 200

            # ...
            sleep(2/1000)
            # ... test that the access token expired for further calls
```

When calling `self.my_client`, I get the error:
`AttributeError: 'TestLogin' object has no attribute 'my_client'`

I've already found this thread [How to use pytest fixtures with django TestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64528957/how-to-use-pytest-fixtures-with-django-testcase), but it doesn't give a solution to use a `pytest.fixture` explicitly in the context of a Django `TestCase`.

Any idea how to access `my_client` inside the `TestLogin` ?

Answer (score 0):

In a Django TestCase, you typically use the setUp method which is excecuted before each test to create the "fixtures" that you need.

In your case your testclass TestLogin(TestCase):

```
class TestLogin(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.my_clent = APIClient()
    def test_jwt_expiration(self):
        simple_jwt_settings = settings.SIMPLE_JWT
        # Force a very short lifetime for the access token
        simple_jwt_settings['ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME'] = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=1)
        with override_settings(SIMPLE_JWT=simple_jwt_settings):
            response = self.my_client.get("/login")
            assert response.status_code == 200

            # ...
            sleep(2/1000)
            # ... test that the access token expired for further calls
```

Depending on other needs, you might look up how to use `setUpClass` and `setUpTestData` that run once for all of the TestCase.

This article goes into good details about this: https://medium.com/an-engineer-a-reader-a-guy/django-test-fixture-setup-setupclass-and-setuptestdata-72b6d944cdef